# Output all possible SQL statementes in a Rails Application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have just inherited a medium sized Rails application and I want to try to optimize it right away. I want to start with the database to ensure that indexes are placed where they need to be an so forth. I therefore need to quickly find out all possible SQL statements that ActiveRecord might make so that I can compare that with the database schema and see where immediate optimization can be made.

In short: Is there an equivalent to *rake routes* which would output all possible SQL templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The hard way

The Rails development log file should contain all of the sql used during the execution of the server. You could grep the file for select statements - perhaps getting a little smarter by using a regexp. Unfortunately you're unlikely to ever be able to process all of the information therein

#### Manage by exception

A better way would be to use some simple monitoring solution to alert you when a request runs too slowly (e.g. [scout](http://scoutapp.com)). Then look at the Rails log file to see if the problem was related to the DB.

#### Use the DB tools

Most DBs will alert you via a log file somewhere if a query runs slowly - MySQL for example has the 'slow queries log'.